# Alternative hash table equality testing for keys

Tags: parallel-processing, mapping, common-lisp, hashtable

SBCL profiling shows one of my Common Lisp hash table functions is consuming a significant amount of time. The function compares two hash tables to determine if they have the same keys:

```
(defun same-keys (ht1 ht2)
  "Returns t if two hash tables have the same keys."
  (declare (hash-table ht1 ht2))
  (when (= (hash-table-count ht1) (hash-table-count ht2))
    (maphash (lambda (ht1-key ht1-value)
               (declare (ignore ht1-value))
               (unless (gethash ht1-key ht2)
                 (return-from same-keys nil)))
             ht1)
    t))
```

Is there a way to speed this up given the hash tables are always `#'eql` with `fixnum` keys? I'm also loading the `lparallel` library, but would it make any sense to somehow parallelize the function in this case?

Edit: The size of the hash tables can range from about 10 to 100 entries. The ht key range extends from 100 up to 999,999,999,999, but the total possible fixnums actually used in this range is sparse. Each ht value is either t or a list. The key-value associations for all hash tables are set at load time. New hash tables are created at run time by copying existing ones and adding or removing entries incrementally. Routine hash table reading, writing, and copying do not seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from low-level optimizations, it depends on the size of the hash-tables and the possible range of values of the keys.

If the key range is not much smaller than the size, you may be faster with vectors instead of hash-tables.  If size is small (less than about 20—50), but range large (e. g. UUIDs), maybe alists are better suited.

If writing to these hash-tables is not the bottleneck, you could wrap your hash-tables with objects holding also some helper data-structure for the key comparison.  This might be some bit-vector marking the used keys, or a complete custom hash of all used keys, or (if size and range are really big) something like a bloom filter.

Parallelizing might make sense if your problem is big enough in some dimension to make it worth the overhead: for example, either the frequency of independent comparisons is very high, or the number of keys per hash-table very big.

One possible low-level optimization is to use `loop` instead of `maphash`, which most of the time can be compiled to much faster code:

```
(loop :for key1 :being :the :hash-keys :of ht1
      :always (nth-value 1 (gethash key1 ht2)))
```

Comment: Appreciate your most excellent discussion of the tradeoffs. The edits above relate to the tradeoffs, if this helps with any further insights. Thank you.

Comment: Given the `lparallel:pmap` cognate function, I'm wondering if something similar is workable for mapping over a hash table. Also surprisingly, loop seems to be slightly slower than maphash in my application.

Comment: As a follow-on matter of interest, I also see a function in the alexandria library that maps over just the keys in a hash table: `(alexandria:maphash-keys fn ht)`. But this is no more speedy than the other two choices mentioned, at least in my application.